# How to allow POST method in flask-admin Inherited Base view?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I've extended the BaseView of flask-admin to create a product view where I can add products to my db. But while submitting. It's showing that the method is not allowed.

```
class ProductsView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def add_products(self):
        form = AddProducts()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("Here")
            name = form.name.data
            price = form.price.data
            discount = form.price.data
            brand = form.brand.data
            description = form.description.data
            image = photos.save(request.files.get('image'))
            add_product = Products(
                name=name, price=price,
                discount=discount, brand=brand,
                desc=description,
                image_1=image
            )
            db.session.add(add_product)
            flash(f"{name} is added to the database successfully!!!", "success")
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        return self.render(template='products/addproducts.html', title="Add Products", form=form)

admin = Admin(app, name='Ekart Admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ModelView(Products, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ProductsView(name='Add Products(Local)'))
```

Here, I just need to allow the post method in the add_product view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try it ?
@expose('/', medthods=['POST'])